# Servlet Response not updating the JSP foreach iterator

Tags: java, jquery, list, servlets, jstl

I am calling a servlet on ready like,

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
        $.ajax({  
            type: "GET",  
            url: "UserInfoDisplay"                       
          });   
    });
```

In my servlet's doGet method I have,

```
SuperUserAdminDAO superUser = new SuperUserAdminDAO();
List<AuthorizeUser> authorizeUserList =superUser.getUserInfo();     
request.setAttribute("userInfo", authorizeUserList);    
request.getRequestDispatcher("/UserAdmin.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

When I print my list, I am able to see it on the console but the change is not getting reflected in my jstl core foreach,

```
<select id="uid">
<c:forEach var="uid" items="${userInfo}">
  <option value="${uid.auid}">${uid.auid}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

What am I missing out?

Comment: how you are printing in jsp

Comment: @PSR I mean I am able to see my list when I use system.out.println in servlet.

Comment: r u getting the result in ajax

Comment: I believe you are intending to make an ajax call after the page loads.So after getting the data from servlet, how are you trying to populate it in UI?

Comment: If you change anything on the JSP those changes get reflected (ex: adding static html)? Also if you add a `<c:out value="${userInfo}"/>
` what you get?

Comment: did you try with `items="${requestScope.userInfo}"` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
      $.ajax({  
        type: "GET",  
        url: "UserInfoDisplay" ,
        success: function(result){ 
          buildSelect(result);
         }                      
      });  

function buildSelect(results)
{
  for(var i in results)
     $('#uid').append('<option value="'+results[i].auid+'">'+results[i].auid+'</option>');

}
```

Comment: I get "results" is not defined.

Comment: I get all values in the drop down as "undefined".

Comment: see the results by using console.log(results) let meknow what are coming

Comment: I get some html page(almost like the content of the same jsp) as result.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31248/discussion-between-prasanna-and-psr)